# What is meant by "find the eigenvectors of a matrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

Let's say I have a question asking me to find the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$ for $A$ (a $3 \times 3$ matrix).

I find that the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$ are all vectors spanned by $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ (a plane).

Can I call $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 2$, even though there is a whole plane of them? I can find a basis for the space but I don't see how I can give a finite number of vectors. Is the correct way to word it that eigenvectors are $\operatorname{span} \{\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \}$?

Comment: Sounds like the right wording to me. At this point you should be used to questions where you cannot list each single element of the solution space, but instead describe the space.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

When you write that "*$\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ are* ***the*** *eigenvectors associated with $\lambda=2$*", the usage of the definite article *the* definitely carries a taint of uniqueness, which is something you don't want.

You could simply say instead that "*$\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$* ***span*** *the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda=2$*", or even better that they *span the $\lambda=2$ eigenspace.* Your last way of writing it, with $\text{span}\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2\}$, is also a good way to do it with fewer words and more symbols, if that is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, sometimes the eigenspace $V_\lambda$ associated to an eigenvalue is more than $1$-dimensional. To find "the eigenvectors" is to find a linearly independent set of eigenvectors for each eigenvalue that span this subspace, i.e. an eigenbasis. (They might not span the whole space if $A$ is not diagonalizable.)

*Edited to clarify:* An eigenvector must be nonzero, so the eigenspace $V_\lambda$ is the subspace of all eigenvectors of the given eigenvalue $\lambda$, together with the zero vector $\mathbf{0}$:
$$
V_\lambda = \{ v \in V \mid A\mathrm{v} = \lambda\mathrm{v} \}. 
$$
You are describing this vector subspace with a minimum of information, so just as you would with *any* subspace, describe a basis for it.

Answer (score 0):

Let‘s review the commonly used terms for eigenvalue problems:

The idea behind eigenvalue problems is that we would like to find the vectors $v \neq 0$ which are mapped to a multiple of themselves under an endomorphism, or, after choosing a basis, a matrix $A$. Meaning, $$A \cdot v = \lambda \cdot v,$$
where $\lambda$ is an element in the underlying field, for example the real numbers.

If there is such a non-trivial vector to a specific $\lambda$ such that this equation holds, $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue. Any $v \neq 0$ which makes the equation true is then called eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, so yes, $u_1$ and $u_2$ are most certainly called eigenvectors!

It is easy to see that if $v$ is an eigenvector, so is any non-zero multiple of $v$! Therefore, the space of all eigenvectors to an eigenvalue together with the zero vector, which is called the eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of the eigenvalue $\lambda$, is usually not finite (And never finite over the real or complex numbers, except you define eigenspaces even for $\lambda$‘s which are not eigenvalues, in which case the eigenspace is $\{0\}$). To go back to your question: You cannot give a finite number of eigenvectors as your answer as there are many more!

So, the correct term for $span(u_1,u_2)$ is eigenspace of the eigenvalue 2.

In case you are a physicist: If they talk about ”the eigenvectors“, they usually mean one should pick an orthonormal basis of the eigenspace, even though this of course does not yield unique results.

Comment: Thanks for the remark! I've edited my post.